# Pass props to react component wrapped in variable

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know how to pass properties to react component wrapped in variable?

```
  export default function App() {
    let mycomponent = <MyComponent />;
    //Here i want to pass props to mycomponent
    return <div className="App">{mycomponent}</div>;
  }
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wave-rwp7j?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
const props = { /* your props */ };
React.cloneElement(mycomponent, props);
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-cache-8pnes?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

As you are expecting `number` prop in your `MyComponent` you can follow this below code.

```
 export default function App() {
    let mycomponent = <MyComponent number={6} />;
    //Here i want to pass props to mycomponent
    return <div className="App">{mycomponent}</div>;
  }
```

Another way you can clone your component, which returns new element.

```
mycomponent = React.cloneElement(mycomponent, { number: 6 });
```

refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to know more about cloning.

Answer (score 0):

First way is just use directly and pass props to your component
Here I am passing value to `title` prop

```
export default function App() {
    return <div className="App"><MyComponent title="Hello" /></div>;
  }
```

Second way is like this

```
 export default function App() {
    let mycomponent = <MyComponent title={"Hello"} />;
    return <div className="App">{mycomponent}</div>;
  }
```